# How to limit Podio API output for complex item resources

Tags: api, podio

Is it possible to limit API response from the `POST /item/app/{app_id}/filter/` for a complex resources with a lot of fields set? I know there is `fields` param and it can be used with some predefined views, like `items.view(micro)`, but this is not a solution for us. We need to explicitly define which fields should be returned, to have in the response only needed fields (optimize the output length as much as possible, but have all needed fields). Can we somehow achieve this by available for now API params or could Podio consider to introduce such functionality in the future API revisions?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `fields()` decorator, to add desired fields to your view.

`items.view(micro).fields(fields,created_on,last_edit_on)`

Unfortunately I don't think it is possible to further filter the number of **Podio Application's Fields** returned under the **REST response's `fields` field** (ugh ).
I couldn't find a way to filter on the Fields defined by the user on the Application.

E.g.

```
[
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "label": "My item field"
        "field_id": 123456778,
        "external_id": "my-item-field"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It's not possible to filter by `my-item-field`.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Rest Api doesn't allow you to limit (select) output fields. (As GraphQL can do)
So, while Podio is on Rest Api - you can't do that.